# When breaking honeyfruit, how long does the health packs last?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you go into river and break the honeyfruit, it drops 5 health packs, that will regenerate both health and mana to whoever walks over it.

I can't remember a time where I just randomly walked up and there were health packs already on the ground.

So how long do they stay on the ground before despawning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They last for 30 seconds after destroying the fruit. I just went on the practice tool and tested this, as I couldn't find any mention of it in the patch notes.

Comment: As a side note: You should consider the Scuttler too. Which will eat them if not interrupted